# How to set equation numbers in lining numerals?

Tags: fonts, xetex, amsmath, libertine

I'm using XeLaTeX with Linux Libertine (using fontspec) and oldstyle numbers.  I'd like, however, to set equation numbers (using `amsmath`'s `\eqref`) in lining numbers.  This does not work:

```
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\Lpnum{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}}
\def\Lpnum#1{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+lnum;+pnum;-tnum;-onum}#1}}
```

In other circumstances, the `\Lpnum` macro does work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

```
\tagform@=macro:
#1->\maketag@@@ {(\ignorespaces #1\unskip \@@italiccorr )}.
l.5 \show\tagform@

? > \maketag@@@=macro:
#1->\hbox {\m@th \normalfont #1}.
l.6 \show\maketag@@@
```

so you probably want to invert the order of

```
 \Lpnum{\tagform@{
```

to

```
 \tagform@{\Lpnum{
```

so that you get choose the font actually used.

Comment: I'm impressed, both by the accuracy and speed of your answer!  Thanks, it works!

Comment: ah that was a good guess, I didn't test as I don't know enough about xelatex to load up the fonts:-)