# Equation tags in lining numerals

Tags: fonts, amsmath, oldstylenums

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50737/5626); I'd like also the tags (typeset by the `\tag` command) to be in lining numerals.  However, inspecting the definition of `\tag` in `amsmath` didn't reveal too much to me - it is `\let` to different macros, depending on (I guess) which exactly environment is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would do it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\tagfont}[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\tagfont#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
123
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\tag{1234567890}\label{x}
\end{equation}
\setcounter{equation}{455}
\begin{equation}
aaa
\end{equation}
456--\eqref{x}--456
\end{document}
```

The important macro is `\maketag@@@`; you can also use the `\Lpnum` method of the other answer, but I believe that this is cleaner.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change the internal macros directly, [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) package is more friendly (c.f. egreg's solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\lining[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}

\newtagform{lining}{(\lining}{)}
\usetagform{lining}

\begin{document}
123
\begin{equation}
a+b=c\tag{1234567890}\label{x}
\end{equation}
\setcounter{equation}{455}
\begin{equation}
aaa
\end{equation}
456--\eqref{x}--456
\end{document}
```